# VBA Formatting Not Putting 0 Into Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA UserForm to input orders into an Excel table.

When the number is 0 instead of putting 0 into the excel table the cell is left blank.

```
OrdersTable.ListColumns("Introducer Tier 2 Cash Fee Percentage").Range(NewRow + 1) = Val(tbSecondaryIntroducerCashFeePercent)
OrdersTable.ListColumns("Introducer Tier 2 Equity Fee Percentage").Range(NewRow + 1) = Val(tbSecondaryIntroducerEquityFeePercent)
OrdersTable.ListColumns("Introducer Tier 2 Cash Fee").Range(NewRow + 1) = Format(CLng(tbSecondaryIntroducerCashFeeNumber), "#,###")
OrdersTable.ListColumns("Introducer Tier 2 Equity Fee").Range(NewRow + 1) = Format(CLng(tbSecondaryIntroducerEquityFeeNumber), "#,###")
```

This is happening to the Introducer Tier 2 Cash Fee & Introducer Tier 2 Equity Fee sections.

Right now I am solving the problem with IF statements but I know in my bones that there is a simple fix I'm just not realizing what it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Change `#,###` to `#,##0`

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom. Dr. braX

Answer (score 2):

Change `#,###` to `#,##0`

A `0` in that place instead means that it will put a number there, whereas a `#` is just a placeholder for a number.